# How to ping website and show status in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with three columns. Websitename, URL, Status. I get website name and URL from xml file. After getting url frm xml file I want to ping the website. If ping success, then status column in gridview will be green. If ping failure, then status column will be red.

Below is my code.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string Instance = node.Attributes["name"].Value.Trim();
    foreach (XmlNode nodeChild in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtIPCheckList.NewRow();

        dr["Instance"] = Instance;
        dr["WebServer"] = nodeChild.Attributes["name"].Value.Trim();
        dr["URL"] = nodeChild.Attributes["IPFQDN"].Value.Trim();
        dr["Status"] = "GREEN"; //hardcoding at the moment.
        dtIPCheckList.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Right now I am hardcoding the status, but i want to ping and show status as per success or failure.

Please guide me.

Comment: You mean the color of the cell will be green? Or the text will be green? Like if (pingReply.Status != "Success") { DR["Status"] = "Red"; Else DR["Status"] = "Green";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote this simple program, and it seems to work:

```
namespace WebsitePingTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Websitename", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("URL", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));

            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Websitename"] = "Google";
            row["URL"] = "www.google.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Websitename"] = "Yahoo";
            row["URL"] = "www.yahoo.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Websitename"] = "xasfjhasfkjh";
            row["URL"] = "www.xasfjhasfkjh.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            var view = new DataView(dt);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = view;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                var url = dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                var ping = new Ping();

                PingReply result = null;
                IPStatus status;
                try
                {
                    result = ping.Send(url);
                    status = result.Status;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    status = IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable;
                }

                if (status != IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable)
                {
                    dataGridViewRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridViewRow.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Website Statuses]